# Global Styles Not getting Reflected for Components Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a button that is common for every component , so instead of styling the components individually i decided to put these button styling in style.css .

But it dosent work all other properties like background and p tag works but not for this button is it beacause of the webkit i am using for this button.

I works when i put it in individual components.

**CSS**

```
input {
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}


input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  height:15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}


input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}


input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  height:15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}


input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="col l3 offset-l9">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" #input>
</div>
```

This is how it should look [image]

This is how it looking now [image]

I tried using view Encapsulation but  i dnt think that makes any diffrence as that is for parent child styling and these are indivdual components

Please help-

Answer (score 1):

to use global styles and disable view css encapsulation
in involved components, add :

```
@Component({
..
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
..
}
```

Comment: do we have to add for every component if we are migrating from 8 to 9? Ours is like moderately big application

Answer (score 0):

Well its working when i tried it

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}


input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  height:15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}


input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}


input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  height:15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}


input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="col l3 offset-l9">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" #input>
</div>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/xr9fvLgd/]

Comment: Peter i know its working but when i place it in global styles.css instead of component css then it doesn't

Comment: maybe component ovewrite your style in global do you have input[type=search] in your component and global and both have other styling in them

Comment: make sure your global link is lower than your components link in the head of your website

Comment: there no styling in component but what i have noticed is matealize css is overdding the style how tio disable styling for one element

Comment: sorry for my late response idk if u can disable styling from on ellement but u can use !important on your styling to make that the boss

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Global Style in the '.angular-cli.json' file and applicable to whole project.

Open your code folder in Visual Studio Code and look for the '.angular-cli.json' file, under the 'apps' array object object, add styles array object.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

Comment: Its already there @MThomas  because all the rest of the styles are working just these button styles are not getting reflected dnt know why